# How to fill Time Selector from database?

Tags: c#

How to fill already saved value in time selector from database?Shall we use a datetime picker only for pick time? I tried like this. I have already value in ShiftType Table. So I just want to retrive it. I have a connection class (conn) and Method(query) dont get confusion with this.

```
string str6= "select Breaktime from ShiftType where Shiftname='" + ddname.SelectedItem.Text + "'";
 SqlDataReader dr6 = conn.query(str6);
  if (dr6.Read())
  {

    TimeSelector1.Value = dr6[0].Tostring();
  }
```

Comment: @Izzy, Kindly find my edited question I have updated what I did

Comment: @Izzy, If it is a text box, then we can retrive the value like TextBbox1.Text=dr6[0].Tostring();. But I dont know how to retrive this value into a time selector.

Comment: What is your `TimeSelector1` object?

Comment: @Jerrington, DateTime time1 = DateTime.Parse(string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", TimeSelector1.Hour, TimeSelector1.Minute, TimeSelector1.AmPm));

Comment: What I mean is what class is it an instance of? `DateTimePicker`? Is that a WinForm app? WPF? You need to be a lot more specific.

Comment: @Jerrington, it s web application and it is not DateTimePicker. Its a third party TimeSelector its class is <%@ Register Assembly="TimePicker" Namespace="MKB.TimePicker" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

Comment: @Signetsoftwaretrainee what is your ddname.SelectedItem.Text value?you can make a TimeSpan from it value

Comment: How is anyone supposed to guess how and if it's possible to set a value if it's a third party control?? I guess you should contact whoever created the control or read the documentation if was provided...

Comment: @M.Azad, ddname.SelectedItem.Text shows Some Shiftname from Shift table. in this table I have some breaktime(values) according to shift name. I want to bring this curresponding value into TimeSelector for editing purpose.

Comment: @Jerrington, K how can we set only time without using a third party timeSelector  I am working with web application so I couldnt find DateTimePicker.

Comment: @Jerrington, If we use DateTimePicker it shows both date and time but I need only time. So this is the reason which I used a third party Timeselector

Comment: What type is this third party control expecting as its value? DateTime? TimeSpan? String? What's in your `dr6[0]`? DateTime? TimeSpan? String?

Comment: @Signetsoftwaretrainee what is your beaketime format in database and what is  correct value for TimeSelector1.Value?

Comment: @Jerrington, it returns string value (only time). In place of TimeSelector if we use Textbox we get the value in Textbox. If You dont mind please check the reply which I given to lzzy

Comment: @M.Azad, In my database I have value like "10:30:00 PM"

Comment: @Signetsoftwaretrainee What isTimeSelector.Value Type?TimeSpan?DateTime?

Comment: It's too much guessing, I understand that you might be a trainee but you need to learn how to ask questions too if you want to learn more (and quicker). Assuming you're retrieving a string value from your database which represents time and your control is expecting a TimeSpan value you could read this MSDN page about TimeSpan.Parse: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9(v=vs.110).aspx. Some additional string operation might be needed (such as Substring).

Comment: @Signetsoftwaretrainee You can create datetime from your string...New DateTime( year, month, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond)